# Having issue with file input in Java

Tags: java, file, input, try-catch

I have to get a integer text file and output the max and min values, using a try catch block to catch errors. I know it has something to do with the fileName scanner near the while loop.

````
    
        
        int currentVal;
        boolean value = true;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        try {
        
        System.out.print("Enter the file name:");
        String fileName = input.next();


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (readFile.hasNext()) {
            currentVal = readFile.nextInt();
            if(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
                max = currentVal;
                min = currentVal;
            } else {
                max = Math.max(max, currentVal);
                min = Math.min(min, currentVal);
            }
            
        
        
        System.out.println("Maximum and Minimums will be printed");
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);

    }

    }}```
````

Comment: You are having *what* issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the flaw is in the following if block:

```
        if(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
            max = currentVal;
            min = currentVal;
        } else {
            max = Math.max(max, currentVal);
            min = Math.min(min, currentVal);
        }
```

Why do you need to update max & min all the time?

You should update your comparison logic as such:

```
            currentVal = readFile.nextInt();
            max = Math.max(max, currentVal);
            min = Math.min(min, currentVal);
```

And initialize max and min before the cycle with max = Integer.MIN_VALUE and min = Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

So there are two issues here, one with where your try/catch is and the other with variable scope. I'm not addressing any logic errors in your calculation, should they exist. Just trying to help get the program to run.

You currently have

```java
try {
   System.out.print("Enter the file name:");
   String fileName = input.next();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("Error occured");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There are two issues here:

1. There are no exceptions that are expected from the two statements in the try block, and consequently the place where the exception *could* be thrown is not handled.
2. `String filename`, since it is present in the try block, is not visible to the code that comes after it (outside the try block)

So what to do?

1. You have the right idea with the try-catch block, just the wrong place! You want it when you try to open the file.
2. Make sure the `String filename` is visible where it needs to be used

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the file name:");
String fileName = input.next();
try {
    Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    while (readFile.hasNext()) {
        currentVal = readFile.nextInt();
        if (readFile.hasNextInt()) {
            max = currentVal;
            min = currentVal;
        } else {
            max = Math.max(max, currentVal);
            min = Math.min(min, currentVal);
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum and Minimums will be printed");
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error occured");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```